# Setting widget background to programmatically generated gradient

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-appwidget

I'm struggling with making my widget to look pretty, but the widget fights back ;(

I have a problem with setting widget layout background to generated linear gradient.

For now, I have found how to generate linear gradient with custom "weigth" of colors for that gradient:

```
public static PaintDrawable createLinearGradient(final int left, final int top, final int right, final int bottom, 
                                                 final int[] colors, final float[] positions)
{
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory shaderFactory = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory()
    {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height)
        {
            LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(left, top, right, bottom, colors, positions, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            return lg;
        }
    };

    PaintDrawable gradient = new PaintDrawable();
    gradient.setShape(new RectShape());
    gradient.setShaderFactory(shaderFactory);

    return gradient;
}
```

And here is a way to set widget background to drawable from drawable folder:

```
int backgroundId =  getDrawableByName(context, "round_transparrent_background");
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.mainLayout, "setBackgroundResource", backgroundId);
```

I need a way to write this command as following:

```
Drawable background =  createLinearGradient(params ... );
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.mainLayout, "setBackgroundResource", background);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RemoteViews are inherently limited to certain functions. This makes some sense when you consider that any information you pass to your `RemoteViews` needs to travel across processes, and not all classes/data types are supported.

There is no way to pass an arbitrary `Drawable` object to `RemoteViews` -- none of the methods support it, and `Drawable` in general is not a class whose data can be marshalled across processes. The reason it works for drawable *resources* is that the resource ID is just an integer, and Android knows how to inflate them into Bitmaps (for pngs) or their respective `Drawable` implementations (for anything declared with XML).

As I see it, the only strategy that might work would be to actually draw the gradient into a `Bitmap` using the `Canvas` APIs and to use an `ImageView` in your AppWidget to act as the background. Then you would call [`remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap(int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) to set the content of the `ImageView`.